# Folder Actions .scpt Not Functioning

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to use this script with Folder Actions. I've tested for functionality within folder actions by enabling a default script, it works. But this script does not seem to function?

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with aFile in added_items
            if the name extension of aFile is "mp3" then
                move aFile to Muisc
            end if
            if the name extension of aFile is "mkv" then
                move aFile to Movies
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with aFile in added_items
            if the name extension of aFile is "mp3" then
                move aFile to "/Users/davidcuster/Music"
            else if the name extension of aFile is "mkv" then
                move aFile to "/Users/davidcuster/Movies"
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Also:

"/Users/davidcuster/Music" = (path to music folder)

"/Users/davidcuster/Movies" = (path to movies folder)

```
  on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with aFile in added_items
            if the name extension of aFile is "mp3" then
                move aFile to path to music folder
            else if the name extension of aFile is "mkv" then
                move aFile to path to movies folder
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Nothing. Thanks for trying, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: I think I can just use Music and Movies? Changes reflected above.

Comment: The code above is correct, I'm not sure what is going on on your side. Have you checked that this is the only folder action attached to your test folder?

Comment: Yes. Still not working. But the default ones work, not other scripts are enabled.

Comment: Got it, it was my bad. It works perfectly. Thanks!